# Bulk Insert Windows Event Log CSV with Format File

Tags: sql, events, logging, insert, bulk

There are several articles on stackoverflow regarding how to import CSVs with double quotes using format files.  I'm attempting to apply the same logic to importing Windows Event logs, but I'm not having any luck.  Here's my SQL code.

```
bulk insert System_logs FROM 'C:\temp\System1.csv' with 
(
    FIRSTROW = 3,
    DATAFILETYPE='char',
    FIELDTERMINATOR='","',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',
    FORMATFILE= 'C:\scripts\system_logs1.fmt' 
)
```

Here's my format file:

```
    12.0
    17

    1       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\""    0     FIRST_QUOTE                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    2       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     1     EventID                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    3       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     2     MachineName                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    4       SQLCHAR             0       4000    "\",\""     3     Data                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    5       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     4     Index                                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    6       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     5     Category                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    7       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     6     CategoryNumber                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    8       SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\"" 7     EntryType                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    9       SQLCHAR             0       4000    "\",\""     8     Message                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    10      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     9     Source                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    11      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     10    ReplacementStrings                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    12      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     11    InstanceId                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    13      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     12    TimeGenerated                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    14      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     13    TimeWritten                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    15      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     14    UserName                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    16      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\",\""     15    Site                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    17      SQLCHAR             0       500     "\"\r\n"    16    Container                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

The error I receive is:
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 2, column 17. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us which windows event log you are trying to import with the format file, because I can see they are formatted differently depending on the event log type( applications, system, setup, forwarded events, security) on my system?

for instance:

- Setup_event_log: no double qoutes present
- System_event_log: only uses double quotes when the information covers multiple lines
- ...

or can you provide us some sample data so we can help you?
I'm trying to help you because I encountered the same problem.

cheers